# How to create a map in controller.js from dynamic form in index.html?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a dynamic form from angular in `index.html` using `ng-repeat` over an array of JSON object. On submit button, I need to pass form data into a post request in form of a map like :

```
{"key":value,"key":value}
```

The key is dynamic label generated in the form and value is the input from a text field or drop-down. Please help me. How I can create a map dynamically? You can find my code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8xS3MMhR765lky5ybGi4?p=preview).

Comment: Don't link your code, include your code here, that way in future this post may still fucntion in case the url breaks.

Comment: @DarkMukke Please have a look now next time i will remember.
https://plnkr.co/edit/8xS3MMhR765lky5ybGi4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. This was a little bit tricky to create a map from dynamic form. Code has been updated on plunker.

Step:

1. I declared a json object response at script.js.
2. Response[filed.attributeLabel] will work as a key and value will be bind when we select or enter some thing in dropdown or text filed avvording to key in scope variable.